# Could not find the ColdFusion Component that exists

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8, application.cfc, fusebox, coldspring

When I use the following locally for development it works, when it is in production it works most of the time, but every so ofter we get the following error using this code:

**Code**

```
CreateObject("component", "model.mThing.Thing");
```

Now the `model` mapping is created in the `Application.cfc` so the `model.mThing.Thing` path should always be pointing to a cfc that exists, and ww should never get the following error..  So what is wrong here?

The environment is CF8 using fusebox and coldspring, and this error only started happening after we started using coldspring to store our factory cfcs, which execute the `CreateObject` code above that causes the error below.

**Error:**

```
"Error","jrpp-839","02/xx/12","xx:yy:zz","appName","Could not find the ColdFusion Component or Interface model.mThing.Thing.  Ensure that the name is correct and that the component or interface exists. The specific sequence of files included or processed is: Z:\domains\x.y.com\root\index.cfm, line: 11 "
coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage$NoSuchTemplateException: Could not find the ColdFusion Component or Interface model.mThing.Thing.                                                                                                                                                                                  
               at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxyFactory.getResolvedFile(TemplateProxyFactory.java:1173)                                                                                                                                                                                                       
               at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxyFactory.getTemplateFileHelper(TemplateProxyFactory.java:1346)                                                                                                                                                                                                 
               at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxyFactory.resolveName(TemplateProxyFactory.java:1289)                                                                                                                                                                                                           
               at coldfusion.cfc.ComponentProxyFactory.getProxy(ComponentProxyFactory.java:38)                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
               at coldfusion.runtime.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:65)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
               at coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.createObjectProxy(CFPage.java:4707)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
               at coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.CreateObject(CFPage.java:4552)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
               at cfThingFactory2ecfc633415381$funcCREATEthings.runFunction(Z:\domains\x.y.com\approot\_Model\mThing\ThingFactory.cfc:11)                                                                                                                                                                       
               at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:418)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
               at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:360)                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
               at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:324)                                                                                                                                                                                                              
               at coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:59)                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
               at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:277)                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
               at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:192)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
               at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invokeUDF(CfJspPage.java:2471)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
               at cfThingFactory2ecfc633415381$funcGETthings.runFunction(Z:\domains\x.y.com\approot\_Model\mThing\ThingFactory.cfc:66)                                                                                                                                                                          
               at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:418)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
               at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:360)                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
               at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:324)                                                                                                                                                                                                              
               at coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:59)                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
               at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:277)                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
               at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:463)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
               at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:453)                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
               at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:320)                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
               at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invoke(CfJspPage.java:2222)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
               at cfjs2ethings2dphotos2ecfm1184443389._factor5(Z:\domains\x.y.com\approot\parsed\js.things-photos.cfm:146)                                                                                                                                                                                      
               at cfjs2ethings2dphotos2ecfm1184443389._factor12(Z:\domains\x.y.com\approot\parsed\js.things-photos.cfm:136)                                                                                                                                                                                     
               at cfjs2ethings2dphotos2ecfm1184443389._factor15(Z:\domains\x.y.com\approot\parsed\js.things-photos.cfm:5)                                                                                                                                                                                       
               at cfjs2ethings2dphotos2ecfm1184443389.runPage(Z:\domains\x.y.com\approot\parsed\js.things-photos.cfm:1)                                                                                                                                                                                         
               at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:196)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
               at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:370)                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
               at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._emptyTcfTag(CfJspPage.java:2661)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
               at cffusebox52ecfm1103700220.runPage(Z:\domains\x.y.com\coreroot\fusebox5\fusebox5.cfm:188)                                                                                                                                                                                                      
               at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:196)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
               at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:370)                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
               at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._emptyTcfTag(CfJspPage.java:2661)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
               at cffusebox42eruntime2ecfmx2ecfm2039615664.runPage(Z:\domains\x.y.com\coreroot\fusebox5\fusebox4.runtime.cfmx.cfm:1)                                                                                                                                                                            
               at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:196)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
               at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:370)                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
               at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._emptyTcfTag(CfJspPage.java:2661)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
               at cfindex2ecfm2041455050.runPage(Z:\domains\x.y.com\wwwroot\index.cfm:4)                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
               at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:196)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
               at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:370)                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
               at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._emptyTcfTag(CfJspPage.java:2661)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
               at cfApplication2ecfc594211230$funcONREQUEST.runFunction(Z:\domains\x.y.com\wwwroot\Application.cfc:112)                                                                                                                                                                                         
               at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:418)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
               at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:360)                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
               at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:324)                                                                                                                                                                                                              
               at coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:59)                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
               at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:277)                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
               at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:192)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
               at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:448)                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
               at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:308)                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
               at coldfusion.runtime.AppEventInvoker.invoke(AppEventInvoker.java:74)                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
               at coldfusion.runtime.AppEventInvoker.onRequest(AppEventInvoker.java:243)                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
               at coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:269)                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
               at coldfusion.filter.RequestMonitorFilter.invoke(RequestMonitorFilter.java:48)                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
               at coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(MonitoringFilter.java:40)                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
               at coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:86)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
               at coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:70)                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
               at coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28)                                                                                                                                                                                                   
               at coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
               at coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:46)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
               at coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
               at coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22)                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
               at coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:175)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
               at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89)                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
               at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:86)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
               at com.intergral.fusionreactor.filter.FusionReactorFilter.b(FusionReactorFilter.java:376)                                                                                                                                                                                                        
               at com.intergral.fusionreactor.filter.FusionReactorFilter.c(FusionReactorFilter.java:254)                                                                                                                                                                                                        
               at com.intergral.fusionreactor.filter.FusionReactorFilter.doFilter(FusionReactorFilter.java:164)                                                                                                                                                                                                 
               at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:94)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
               at coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42)                                                                                                                                                                                                    
               at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
               at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:94)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
               at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.service(FilterChain.java:101)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
               at jrun.servlet.ServletInvoker.invoke(ServletInvoker.java:106)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
               at jrun.servlet.JRunInvokerChain.invokeNext(JRunInvokerChain.java:42)                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
               at jrun.servlet.JRunRequestDispatcher.invoke(JRunRequestDispatcher.java:286)                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
               at jrun.servlet.ServletEngineService.dispatch(ServletEngineService.java:543)                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
               at jrun.servlet.jrpp.JRunProxyService.invokeRunnable(JRunProxyService.java:203)                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
               at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$ThreadThrottle.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:428)                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
               at jrunx.scheduler.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:66)
```

Comment: What mode is your Fusebox app set to? Production?

Comment: yes production, though I don't think that will matter.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem recently, different context.

Turned out that the Administrator setting was different between production.

Enable Per Application Settings 
When checked, per application settings are enabled server-wide. If unchecked, per app settings are disabled server-wide.

Without that set the application can't set application specific mappings.

Comment: the setting is on in production and locally, so this is not the issue, nice guess thou!

Comment: On the server where id doesn't work, dump the this scope to ensure the mapping is set. Also ensure there is no conflicting mapping setup in Administrator

Comment: there are no mappings set in the server admin, tho I'm thinking about trying that.

Comment: I am certain that the application mapping is set most of the time, the fail is only intermittent and seemingly random.

Answer (score 2):

[This blog post](http://www.jonhartmann.com/index.cfm/2009/3/4/ColdFusion-Intermittently-Cannot-Find-CFC-Part-II) mentioned a similar problem to ours, we've set the mappings in the cf server administrator and we'll see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

**To help others like me getting here for a solution:**

I had the same problem and by further testing I inferred that the CFCs are cached by application server in a convoluted way and renaming the file didn't work as expected. I tried restarting the application server service(ColdFusion Application Server) and it started working as expected.